# Check WordPress Version in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, version

I'm a WordPress designer & developer and I want to know if if it's possible to check my WordPress version in tables of MySQL database to print it in an administration panel page?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you have tried so we can help you better. We like to see code over here.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Should be in wp_options table, the field is called db_version. So, yes, it's possible.

You can run this SQL command (substitute your table name if different):

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` where option_name = 'db_version'
```

Make sure to consult the codex, as the db_version looks different from the wp version. for instance:

> For Version 3.1, the database version (db_version in wp_options)
> changed to 17056, and the Trac revision was 17485.

See https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions for a cross reference of db_version (database version) to WordPress release.

Alternatively, you can find the file in the WordPress installation, inside the folder "wp-incudes". The file is called `version.php` and defines a global variable like so:

```
/**
 * The WordPress version string
 *
 * @global string $wp_version
 */
$wp_version = '3.7.1';
```

Comment: The following site also shows a table of WordPress version numbers (e.g. 3.x.x) with matching 'db_version' values: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions

Comment: @DerekLee is the MVP.

Comment: As Alk's answer points out, this only gives the database version, which (usually) doesn't exactly identify the Wordpress version.  But the answer includes another field that does give it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that the accepted answer to this question is no longer accurate.

You cannot use db_version from wp_options because the db_version does not always change between Wordpress updates (eg. with maintenance releases). I have multiple installations of Wordpress and I have confirmed that the db_version for v5.8 has remained the same in v5.8.1. Additionally, if you look at the reference at http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions you will also find that the same DB version numbers are used across multiple releases of Wordpress. Therefore, you are unable to rely on db_version to determine what version of Wordpress you are running.

However, you can query _site_transient_update_core in wp_options and look in the option_value for the version number after "version_checked". For example:

```
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE (option_name IN ('_site_transient_update_core'));
```

Would produce an output in option_value and I find in there:

```
s:15:"version_checked";s:5:"5.4.7";
```

My Wordpress version *is* v5.4.7.

Reference: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/obtaining-wp-version-from-database/ which provides further information on the _site_transient_update_core database option and the reliability of querying it.

Comment: Looking at the Codex table, I guess the accepted answer has always been inaccurate.  The first reused db_version was in v1.5.1 in 2005, and before v1.2.2 in 2004, they didn't even have a db_version.